# make a navigation button using a div with a link inside it

Tags: html, css, button

i just started programming and I wanted to try css with html. However, I keep running into errors like these where I want a button, however when displayed on browser the said button becomes a link.
can someone explain?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Linking External Style Sheets</title>

    <style>
      h1 {
        color: blue;
      }
      a {
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      a:hover {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div><p><em>Click here:</em>
         <a class="w3-btn" href="http://www.w3schools.com">Link Button</a>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I wanted to give it a border, background and text color also, and make it change when theres a mouse over it with the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a button then simply use `<button>` instead of `<a>`:

`<button class="w3-btn" href="http://www.w3schools.com">Link Button</button>`

However, you can't use href with a button since buttons are suited for forms. In this case you can either style the link to look like a button (@RahulB answer) or wrap the (real) button in a form which submits to http://www.w3schools.com.

```
<form action="http://www.w3schools.com" method="POST">
         <button class="w3-btn" type="submit>Link Button</button>
</form>
```

Comment: on a separate topic, how is this done to a external style sheet

Comment: Place your style inside a css file then import the file to your html with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylefile.css">`. Place this code in the `<head>` section of the html code.

Answer (score 1):

You can style the link as button --

```
   a{
        color: blue;
        text-decoration: none;
        border : 1px solid black;
        padding : 10px;
        background-color : cyan;
        border-radius: 10px;
        appearance : button;
      }
```

Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/vgwgsoqt/1/